# Changelist management tool like Intellij Idea

Tags: svn, changelist

Intellij IDEA has the following features in changelist management. I am searching for similiar functionality for the windows platform. That way, I do not have to open IDEA just for changelist management.

I would like these features which are present in Intelij IDEA:

1. Define a set of directories to watch for changes
2. Define a default changelist where the changed files would go.
3. Change the default changelist.
4. Move files among the available changelists

Answer (score 0):

eclipse kind of does the same things with the changelist in IDEA. Check out this article [scroll to the part about changes](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/06/whats-cool-in-intellijidea-part-i.html) 
. he gives you a side by side view of how eclipse does it and how jetbrains implemented it in IDEA

Comment: Yes, I currently use the Mylyn with task focused facilities. After making the post I realized the requirement I was asking for is probably bigger than it seems. It is tied in concept to task based work flow and integration with task repositories in turn becomes a requirement.

I asked the question because netbeans currently do not have a way to create changelists (there is a request and I voted, but it seems that it would take some time) to group the changes. I wonder how people get by it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)? It can easily manage changelists through the *Check for modifications* dialog.

Comment: But I think it will not pick up new changes from  a set changelist. Would it? 

Changes could be coming from different directories.

Comment: Do you have any answer Susanta or Yossi?